# How to run a LOCAL webserver on tails

Tags: tails, server, firewall, web-hosting

I am running the latest TailsOS and would like to run and access a web service locally for myself. Just opening the index.html file in the TOR browser does not work, so I need some minimal web server hosting my `app` directory.

I tried both `busybox httpd` and the node http server with no success. Whenever I try to open localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8080 (both services are exposed on these ports respectively), I get nothing in my TOR browser. I also tried starting `nginx` but the service fails to start after installation (which should automatically start an nginx service).

I assume all of the above issues are firewall issues, but can't figure out why I wouldn't be able to access such services locally as I anyway do not plan to expose them to the internet. Any pointers how to make that work would help!

Comment: Do I understand you right that you want to run an Onion Service or do you just want to display a static HTML file? Do you have configured Tor to run an Onion Service? If so, how did you set it up?

Comment: @JensKubieziel I just want to display a HTML file. But `File` -> `Open` does not work as some components won't run when just loading static HTML files so I need to serve that as a local webserver. No need to run an Onion Service (unless that makes it easier).

Comment: So in that case it might be sufficient to create a new directory, change into it and run `python3 -m http.server 34343`. Now you place a HTML file into that directory and point your browser to http://127.0.0.1:34343

Comment: Thank you @JensKubieziel I just tried exactly that with a minimal HTML file in a separate folder, went into that folder to start `python3 -m http.server 34343` and then opened `http://127.0.0.1:34343` as well as `http://0.0.0.0:34343` but the Tor Browser simply says `Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:34343`.

Comment: This doesn't work in Tor Browser. You can't connect to localhost. You'll need another browser.

Answer (score 1):

To access `localhost` with Tor Browser in Tails you can use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -qxF "user_pref(\"network.proxy.no_proxies_on\", \"127.0.0.1\");"  '/home/amnesia/.tor-browser/profile.default/user.js' || echo "user_pref(\"network.proxy.no_proxies_on\", \"127.0.0.1\");"  >> '/home/amnesia/.tor-browser/profile.default/user.js'
```

what it does:

- write with `echo` a rule in `user.js` allowing access to `127.0.0.1` (localhost)
- the `grep` part checks if the line already exists before writing

(you need to restart the Tor Browser after that)

You also need to open the firewall, here is the rule I use to run Hugo on Tails (on port 1313):

`# iptables -I OUTPUT -d localhost -o lo -p tcp --dport 1313 -m owner --uid-owner amnesia -j ACCEPT;`

Answer (score 0):

In tails, there is an option to use [Unsafe Browser](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Unsafe_Browser/). It should be available in your version of Tails out of the box.

> The Unsafe Browser is run by a separate clearnet user, wich is allowed
>   to make TCP connections to any port, and UDP DNS queries; access to
>   local services like Tor etc. are blocked so it cannot interfere with
>   them if compromised. Restricting the TCP ports to HTTP(S) and DNS only
>   is not done since some captive portals use non-standard ports. Port
>   restrictions are a pretty weak defense any way since just one open
>   port is enough to do anything.